# C# SortedDictionary efficiency in comparison to C++ std::map::insert behaviour

Tags: c#, c++, sorteddictionary

Is there an equivalent to C++'s `std::map::insert` but for a C# `SortedDictionary` (or similar container) that also indicates success or failure to insert, and which also provided access to the existing key-value pair if insertion failed?

In essence:  I want to try to add a new key & value pair, or if a matching key already exists, get its associated value and do something to it, **without** incurring the potentially (subjectively) hefty costs of 2 lots of traversal of the container, which is trival to do in C++?

As far as I can see, I can try and add a new key-value pair (which must do some amount of taversal of the container). If it fails, I have to catch an exception that indicates the key already exists, then I have to find the existing k-v pair (presumably another traversal of the container) to get the associated value that I can now modify.  Alternatively, I can just search for whether the key exists in the first place (one traversal).  If not, then I want to add a new k-v pair (which may well involve a lot of the same traversal work).  Either way, the worst case is 2 lots of potentially expensive traversals, while C++'s std::map::insert gives an efficient mechanism to achieve what I want, only ever using 1 traversal.

Comment: So what is your question? Seems like you already got your answer.

Comment: "potentially hefty costs"  Traversing a balanced search tree once isn't going to be hefty.  While it's nice to avoid even small costs where possible, it's at least important to understand what things are and are not actually expensive.

Comment: Remember that if you really need, you can take the source of [`SortedDictionary<,>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedDictionary.cs) from Microsoft's Github and modify it. It is distributed under the MIT license, that is one of the most permissive licenses there is.

Comment: And see these issues that were open on github about similar arguments: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1942 and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31126 and

Comment: AddOrUpdate from [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) can do that I don't know for the perf.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Re. "So what is your question?"  It's already in there twice but I'll try and rephrase it a third way: Is there a way to add to a SortedDictionary-like container in c# where you either add a new k-v pair but, if a key already exists, modify the existing associated value, without having to traverse the container twice?

Comment: Bad assumptions, surely because you did not try it.  No traversal, SortedDictionary uses red-black tree, insertion complexity is O(log n).  Same as std::map.

Comment: @Servy Re. "Traversing a balanced search tree once isn't going to be hefty".  I don't think 'hefty' is an abolute, objective term :) However you want to quantify it, I don't want to do it twice if there's a more efficient way to do things (still in vanilla c#) along the lines of the std::map::insert example.

Comment: @HansPassant Re."No traversal": Do you think the word 'traversal' means linearly walking though memory of a data structure?  You wouldn't call walking through a tree data structure 'traversal'? I think there must be some language confusion:  Replace the world 'traversal' in my question with whatever you call searching/walking through any container.

Comment: Whatever, key is that the algorithm is the same.  Try it.

Comment: @DragandDrop Thank you. It looks very much like ConcurrentDictionary will allow this single-traversal behaviour through either 'AddOrUpdate' or 'GetOrAdd'. Thanks again.  Why not post your comment as and answer and get magic stack points?

Comment: @HansPassant The key is that I think you've missed the question, which wasn't, "Am I safe to assume that a C# Dictionary Add/search is a linear search?", which seems to be what you thought I was asking; it was "Can we avoid double traversal (like we can in C++ through use of the std::map::insert return pair) for the case I described above, but with c# dictionary-like containers?"

Comment: Why do you even care for that? If you are after plain erformance, that use the most performant language, which is C IMHO. If you want something readable than use a managed language such as C#. I doubt those nano-seconds you *could* (without actually having measured) lose by making 2 or 3 more "walks" thorugh a tree won´t hurt much. Usually your *actual* performance-problems - if you have them at all - are not related to the whriong dictionary but somewhere else. Btw: does you map needs a sorting? A plain `Dictionary<T, U>` will probably do the same also a bit faster.

Comment: Having said this what is your *actual* goal? Or is this some kind of academic discussion on the most performant data-structures? Do you try to handle a real-world problem here? Do you actually have some performance-issue you´re trying to solve or do you only *think* you may have one?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Are you _still_ asking me what my actual question is?  I realise it's a very common case on S.O.; comments from people who fail (or refuse) to focus on the actual question asked and instead try to second-guess what they think the question must _really_ be about.  I can put it down to just being well-intentioned for the first time of asking but beyond that: Do us all a favour and stick to the question. I'm sorry if I'm not giving you the question that you're clearly itching to try and answer.  If you don't know the answer to this question, there's a simple course of action to take

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others, the lack of answers leaves me to conclude that there's no equivalent to the nice "try to insert a new key-value into a map, but if the key is already in there, tell me and give me that existing key & value" operation like std::map::insert **for the standard Dictionary or SortedDictionary in c#**.  This does seem like an oversight in the design of these containers.

However, credit to @DragandDrop in the comments above for the answer that there is ConcurrentDictionary's 'AddOrUpdate' or 'GetOrAdd', which will allow the requested behaviour in a single traversal (although, obviously with additional locking mechanism overhead, which, depending on the use, may outweigh double-traversals of regular Dictionary/SortedDictionary containers).